# how does recusrive function call work in javascript

Tags: javascript, python, recursion

I am trying to port the algorythm seen here https://ideone.com/26G1fB (written in python) to javascript.

```
def divide(arr, depth, m):
    if len(complements) <= depth:
        complements.append(2 ** (depth + 2) + 1)
    complement = complements[depth]
    for i in range(2):
        if complement - arr[i] <= m:
            arr[i] = [arr[i], complement - arr[i]]
            divide(arr[i], depth + 1, m)

m = int(raw_input())

arr = [1, 2]
complements = []

divide(arr, 0, m)
print arr
```

i came un with that :

```
var bracketize = function(arr, depth, m) {
  if (complements.length <= depth) {
    complements.push(2 ** (depth +2) + 1)
    }
    var complement = complements[depth]

  for ( i = 0; i < 2; i++ ) {   
    if (complement - arr[i] <= m) {
      arr[i] = [arr[i], complement - arr[i]]      
      bracketize(arr[i], depth + 1 , m)
    }
  }
}

var m = 16
var arr = [1, 2]
var complements = []

bracketize(arr, 0, m)

console.log(JSON.stringify(arr))

// expected result [[[[1, 16], [8, 9]], [[4, 13], [5, 12]]], [[[2, 15], [7, 10]], [[3, 14], [6, 11]]]]
// actual result : [[[[1,16],8],4],2]
```

here a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/9umgwhoa/

It seem to be something in the way js make recursive call versus python but i can't figure out what.

Any pointer on where the difference between the 2 code lie would be appreciated

Comment: What's the question? "Any pointer" is quite broad.

Comment: Sorry, question should have been: how to get expected result from my code instead of actual result ? but i wanted, if possible the have the reason why it didn't work as is.

Comment: You were only missing `var` inside i declaration in your loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you need a local variable `i`. Without you create a global variable and any loop increment the variable without respecting the local scope.

```js
var bracketize = function (arr, depth, m) {
    if (complements.length <= depth) {
        complements.push(2 ** (depth + 2) + 1)
    }
    var complement = complements[depth],
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        if (complement - arr[i] <= m) {
            arr[i] = [arr[i], complement - arr[i]];
            bracketize(arr[i], depth + 1, m);
        }
    }
};

var m = 16,
    arr = [1, 2],
    complements = [];

bracketize(arr, 0, m);

console.log(arr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```